# Make html inbuilt messenger

Tags: html, email, contacts

I'm not really sure how to phrase this question, but how would you make a messaging system in html. Not something like a contact form, but an actual messaging area, like intercom, just free?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!, Unfortunately, This question is a little bit too vague, it asks very generally for what would constitute a tutorial instead of asking a specific question. Therefore it is not suitable for stackoverflow as Stackoverflow is not a tutorial provider or a free code writing service, I recommend new users to review the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of stackoverflow for tips on asking questions that are well-suited for the site and best enable the community to provide helpful feedback. Goodluck :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JavaScript Library **Socket.io** and PHP/Node.js You can make real-time Dynamic Chat application Using **JavaScript/HTML/CSS** but first of all you need to learn how to use socket.io And I can suggest you can visit YouTube for it.

I have watched a similar video.
[Here is a tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jD7FnbI76Hg)

Comment: @Sam its my pleasure to help you